# Design Class for deep copy of SAP PS Project object

Tags: oop, abap, sap-erp

I started my development creating a "ZProject" class that was only used to read or update a SAP PS Project header information, so it only had 1 structure attribute with the PROJ table type.

Now I need to add a really complex operation "Copy" full project. This means that I read the full reference PS Project hierarchy, WBS elements, activities, milestones, costs... then I rename the IDs and finally save the copy using a BAPI call. Since the class ZProject does not have all these attributes, I did it in a static method, but I would like to do it in a different way. The options I considered are the following:

1. Add all the necessary attributes to the ZProject class (WBS elements, hierarchy, activities...). The constructor will not populate them because they are not always needed, but if a get method needs them and detects that are empty, then it will trigger kind of "init" method that loads all the information. Finally I implement a deep copy instance method that renames the necessary IDs and saves to the database using a BAPI.
2. The first option makes it possible that the class reads the private attributes accessing directly without using a getter, therefore without triggering the init method. A future developer could be confused for not understanding that even privately you have to use the getters. Then an alternative solution is to create a class ZProjectFull with a constructor that already reads everything and finally the same deep copy method. If I do this, should the ZProjectFull inherit from ZProject?

Do you have better ideas about how to do this? Should I implement a clone() method instead of deep copy maybe?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I need to add a really complex operation "Copy" full project. This
>   means that I read the full reference PS Project hierarchy, WBS
>   elements, activities, milestones, costs... then I rename the IDs and
>   finally save the copy using a BAPI call. Since the class ZProject does
>   not have all these attributes, I did it in a static method,

No, you can still do the deep clone in a **instance** method. You define a copy method returning a new instance of `ZProject`. Inside the copy method, you get the header info of the current instance of `ZProject` , and read the full reference PS Project hierarchy, WBS elements, activities, milestones, costs... then rename the IDs and finally save the copy using a BAPI call. In the end, you return a new instance with new header info. You can even do a chained call of copy. Furthermore this `copy` method is lazy-init too because it only read dependent child information when the caller calls it.

> Do you have better ideas about how to do this? Should I implement a
>   clone() method instead of deep copy maybe?

The method name is not important. You can have it `clone`() or `copy`() or `deep_copy`() as long as this method signature is meaningful because they are all making sense.

Comment: Thanks, I see your idea but with this approach I can't keep the data that I already had during the copy process and it forces me to read again from the database since I need that information.

Comment: I mean you can always buffer the child data as private instance attributes. On the other hand, the child data can be modified by others during the multiple copy processes. It is just a trade off between performance and data correctness.

Answer (score 1):

```
CLASS zproject DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS constructor IMPORTING project_header.
    METHODS clone RETURNING VALUE(result) TYPE REF TO zproject.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    DATA project_header TYPE <whatever>.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS zproject IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD clone.
    DATA(data) = read_all_project_data( project_header ).
    DATA(modified_data) = assign_new_ids( data ).
    save_to_db( modified_data ).
    result = NEW zproject( modified_data-project_header ).
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

`Clone` is the prevalent name for this type of operation. It's an instance method, because you clone an object that you already have. You can avoid having to re-read the data you already have by handing it over to the constructor. You shouldn't add all the data to your class as members because they are needed solely in the `clone` method.

Comment: Thanks Florian. This is actually how I did it after moving from static to instance method, but I still have the doubt about keeping the data since I need it in other scenarios other than the "clone" method. You say I could hand it to the constructor but then this would require that in the scenario where I don't need all the data (ZProject header update), I should provide all these information to the constructor which is not acceptable. So I still doubt if I should have 2 classes (Full/HeaderOnly), a single class with "optional" constructor members or another alternative that I can't imagine

Comment: That’s a classic question. “I have a large object of which I usually need only parts, but always different ones - how do I design my class(es)?” Typical solutions will take the single class apart into multiple classes with clear, disjunct responsibilities. Your project could be a set of classes like Project, InvolvedParty, Plan, Goal, etc. The classes would use each other. Complex operations would involve one or more of them. Copying could be a large-scale operation over all of them. For a half-OO solution, you might want to have a look at BOPF, by the way. It’s part of NetWeaver.